Problemas al ejecutar comando de expo en vs code
Cada que intento ejecutar este comando "npx expo start" en mi proyecto de expo con react-native me da este error:
 juanc@Juan_Carlos  C:\2APRENDIENDO\PROGRAMACION\React-Native\delivery-app  master  npx expo start
Starting project at C:\2APRENDIENDO\PROGRAMACION\React-Native\delivery-app
Starting Metro Bundler
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/51.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6812:568:443
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/51.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6812:568:443
at ClientRequest. (C:\2APRENDIENDO\PROGRAMACION\React-Native\delivery-app\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1501:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Lo intento con mis datos celulares o en otra casa y si funciona, el internet de mi casa si es rapido, tengo 199.6 mbps de descarga y 68.3 de subida. alguien sabe si este problema de ip o algo así?

Hola Juan, bienvenido, has verificado si el Firewall no bloquea tu aplicación?.

Prueba entrar directamente a esa URL con el navegador a ver si puedes

Al entrar a la URL si me aparecen datos en formato JSON @Yussef

¿Cómo puedo verificar si el firewall bloquea la aplicación? @MarcePuente

Eso depende de que firewall estes usando, puedes buscar en el blog del que usas, ahí te sabran orientar.
